# Exclude part of a String during pattern matching in Scala

Tags: regex, string, scala

I have a simple enough problem. In my unit test I compare expected vs actual output as a String value. Now part of the string is a randomly generated unique ID which causes the test to fail every time. Is there a way I can specify my test to only match part of the actual and ignore text between two points in the string.  A function like -

```
def isMatch(expected : String, actual : String , ignoreFrom : String , ignoreTo : String)
```

Also, since this is a candidate for pattern matching, could some one point me to a pattern match/regex for Dummies kind of a tutorial?

Comment: Visit this links it will be helpfull for you [link1](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Pattern-matching-on-strings-td1947939.html) [link2](http://johlrogge.wordpress.com/2008/10/06/scala-nugget-pattern-matching-and-lists/)

Comment: ignoreFrom is String or Int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Scala [extractors](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_extractors.htm) is what you want. You can specify extractor to match only specific part of the string.

Here is some example:

```
object IgnoreBetween {
    def unapply(str: String): Option[(String, String)] = {
        val parts = str split "\\."
        if (parts.length == 3){
            Some(parts(0), parts(2))
        }else{
            None
        }
    }
}

object Main extends App {
    "part1.somerandom.part2" match {
        case IgnoreBetween("part1", "part2") => println("matches")
        case _ => println("doesn't match")
    }
}
```

"Programming in Scala" and "Scala in depth" have amazing examples on pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

We have created our custom matchers to deal with variable strings, basically using regex to express the expected outcome for a test. The cases where this is useful are plenty: A variable ID like in your case, different server URL's like when we run tests in QA lines, dates,...

What you want is some generic pattern matcher, something like:

```
def matches(expected : String, actual : String) = {
    val pattern = expected.r.pattern
    pattern.matcher(actual).matches
}
```

Example usage (on the REPL):

```
scala> matches("user id='(.+)' retrieved", "user id='12345' retrieved")
res1: Boolean = true

scala> matches("user id='(.+)' retrieved", "user id='12345' not found")
res2: Boolean = false
```

Comment: We use cucumber for testing, and this resource is quite OK on simple regex usage for test purposes. It's cucumber related, but gives you a good idea on how to match expected inputs: http://www.richardlawrence.info/2010/07/20/just-enough-regular-expressions-for-cucumber/